# How to iterate over the "params" of an item ZOO Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, zoo

The item of my interest is in the **__zoo_item** table. My query:

```
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('params')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__zoo_item'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$resultado = $db->loadObjectList();
```

The contents of **params** is a JSON like this:

```
 {
    "metadata.title": "",
    "metadata.description": "",
    "metadata.keywords": "",
    "metadata.robots": "",
    "metadata.author": "",
    "config.enable_comments": "0",
    "config.primary_category": "27"
}
```

I need to retrieve the value of **primary_category**. That is, I need retrieve: **27**. How do I do that? I try to recover it as follows:

```
foreach ($resultado as value) {
    if ( is_object($value) ) {
        echo $value->config.primary_category;
    }
}
```

This is the best way to do this?
The browser returns this: **primary_category**. How to retrieve the value: 27?

Answer (score 0):

ZOO syntax is a bit different.  Check this out: http://yootheme.com/zoo/documentation/developers/accessing-element-data

Comment: Please expand this answer so that it not a link-only post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is the canonical way to access ZOO parameter values, but using your method you probably want something like:

```
$value = json_decode($value);
$primary_category = $value->{'config.primary_category'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot in property name is causing the issue. Multiple ways to solve it:

1. Assign property name to a variable:

   ```
   $value = json_decode($value);

   $property = 'config.primary_category';

   echo $value->$property;
   ```
2. Enclose property value in curly brackets:

   ```
   $value = json_decode($value);

   echo $value->{'config.primary_category'};
   ```
3. Turn params into Registry object (this is the Joomla way):

   ```
   use Joomla\Registry\Registry;

   $value = new Registry($value);

   echo $value->get('config.primary_category');
   ```